# How to monitor routing decision on a linux router

Tags: logging, routes, iptables

I have a linux server that realizes the routing between my local network and my two Internet connections (on 2 physical network cards).

I have configured my server :

1) With iptables, I use PREROUTING rules on the table mangle to mark packets from my local area:

- If no mark, routing use the default table
- If mark = x0001, routing use the specific table x0001

2) With iptables, I use FORWARD rules on the table filter to forward trafic from my local area to the internet cards

3) With "ip route" command, I constuct two tables of routing with different gateway

This configuration works perfectly since many months.

Today, I have a user who switches alternately of internet connections. 
I have logged the PREROUTING rules on iptables and I see that packets from this user, are already marked x0001 regardless of situations.

My conclusion : this packets should be used the same routing table so the same gateway and I think there is error during the routing decision

How can I monitor the routing decision ? 
What is the process that takes this routing decision ? Is it iptables ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create some kind of script to parse the output of commands that can "watch" what is happening with that routing tables. You can use `ip route get` command.

Look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ch11s07.html)

I found these stuff [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192008/tools-for-debugging-routing-tables-on-a-linux-machine)

I hope it helps.